# date field values are wrong while importing csv into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

I am importing csv file into mysql using load data. My load data command is as mentioned below.

```
load data local infile 'D:/mydata.csv' into table mydb.mydata 
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines
(SrNo,SourceFrom,@var_updated,Title,First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name,Designation,Company_Name,@var_dob,Office_Mobile_No)  

set updated = str_to_date(@var_updated,'%Y-%m-%d'), dob = str_to_date(@var_dob, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

I am getting different values in my "Updated" and "DOB" columns. Such values are different in my .csv file.

[image]             [image]

First image is from mysql workbench while another is of csv.

Also, I sat "office_mobile_no" column's format to 'number' in csv. But its showing number like this. 
[image]

When I double click on it, then only it shows the real number like 9875461234. It imports the same in mysql too. How do I get original number in a specific column? Also why my imported date values are differ from csv's date columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points that I can see:

1. It looks from your screenshot like the data in your CSV file for "updated" is in d-m-Y format, but you're telling the import to look for Y-m-d. I think you need to change

`set updated = str_to_date(@var_updated,'%Y-%m-%d')`

to

```
set updated = str_to_date(@var_updated,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

And the same for DOB field as well, assuming your CSV has that in the same format.

2. You said *I sat "office_mobile_no" column's format to 'number' in csv.* CSV is a text file format, it doesn't store any information about how to display data. What you're seeing is just how Excel decides to display large numbers by default. You can change that, but your changes won't be saved when you save it to CSV, because the CSV file format doesn't include that sort of information. Try opening the file in Notepad++ and seeing the real format of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding point 2, can I make changes in the original file which is in Excel and then save it as CSV? Like I set a format of a specific column as number and then save as it in csv? will it work that way? Is there any other way to import a file with all the formats into mysql except csv?

Comment: If you set the format of a specific column in Excel, then save as CSV, it won't save it because as I said above, CSV doesn't store format information. You'd need to change the underlying data. Excel formatting is just for display purposes, not data storage. I would suggest you import it to MySQL just as it is. If you then want to display it in a certain format somewhere else than write some code to format it when you display it to the user. This is a good programming / data storage principle in general - store the data in its raw format, and then change the display of it to suit each use case

Comment: Ohk but how would I get original number then? If I import it as it is in mysql, and in mobile_no, it will show number as "98E+11" then how would I get its original number which is 9875461234 in mysql?

Comment: look in your CSV file using a text editor (e.g. notepad). What does it have in that column? I bet it has 9875461234? If so, then that is the value which will be imported into MySQL.

Comment: I've opened my csv file with notepad, its showing number as "98E+11" not as 9875461234. How to resolve it?

Comment: did you save that file direct from Excel? Which version of Excel? Or was it created some other way?

Comment: I have Excel 2007. I've saved it as CSV from Excel.

Comment: I have Excel 2010. Just tried it. Pasted 9875461234 into Excel in cell A1. Changed format to number (with 0 decimal places). Save as CSV. CSV file contains "9875461234" and nothing else. If I change the format back to "General" and save as CSV again, I get exactly the same result.

Comment: I did the same. I changed format to number with decimal 0 places. It even showed me that original number. Then I saved my excel file and closed it. When I opened it again, its showing me data with "E+" . If I click on the cell, right click on it, then also its showing me format to number with decimal 0. Then why its still with E+?

Comment: that's because CSV doesn't save the format you chose, so Excel guesses the format. Change the format (if you like, it won't matter), save the file as CSV, then open the CSV in notepad. What do you get when you look at it in Notepad?

Comment: But I made changes in Excel only. After your very first explanation, I've made this change in Excel only. Then I saved my Excel file. Then after I saved it as CSV. Let me check again.

Comment: I have a very huge data, 900000+. Excel is taking too much time whenever I try to do any thing in it.

Comment: just try the principle with a single row of data. once that is right then apply it to the whole file :-)

Comment: Its still showing same in CSV. Can you help how to resolve it?

Comment: Or can I write a code to convert exponential to original number using sql after importing the data as it is in mysql?

Comment: I don't really understand what is going wrong here. Get the _original_ Excel file with the source data in it. Copy a couple of rows. Paste into a new workbook (normal paste, not paste as text or whatever). Save that directly to CSV (without messing with formatting etc). See what it looks like in Notepad. It should display the raw numbers, unformatted.

Comment: yeah you could probably write something in SQL to reformat it, but you shouldn't have to.

Comment: I've opened in Notepad, now its showing actual number , not with that E+ sign. But when I import it in mysql, its giving me with E+ . My original data is in excel, I saved it as CSV only for import purpose. Is there any other format in which If i import then get this actual number rather than getting exponential notification?

Comment: once you've imported it into mysql, what software are you using to view it?  Also what is the data type of the column you imported it to? Whatever viewer you are using could be formatting the data in order to display it to you. You might have to override that default.

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE to view it. Columns for Mobile Numbers are of int data type. But its storing the same number as "2147483647" instead of "9875461234". Values which are having E+, showed value as  "2147483647" only. So I changed the column to varchar(255) from int. and in varchar, its showing the number like this -"98E+11"

Comment: create your column as bigint, not int. These numbers are too large for a 32-bit integer. 2147483647 is the largest value it's possible to store in a signed int field. If you try to insert a larger value, MySQL will just use that max value instead. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: also, if the varchar version is showing the E+ value, it sounds like you didn't import the correct CSV file (the one with the raw numbers in). It would only do what you describe if the value in the CSV file was actually stored as the literal text "98E+11". I tried inserting 9875461234 into a varchar field in my own MySQL database and sure enough it stored it as "9875461234"

Comment: Let me try with bigint. It showed me same 98E+11 in varchar too. I am importing correct csv file. I made sure about it.

Comment: Great help. wouldn't be possible without all your support.